# Create TRIGGER in MySQL - need to perform INTERSECT function

Tags: mysql

Basically i want to perform these two queries and perform an intersect operation:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT C.hospital_id FROM hospital.consulta C 
INNER JOIN hospital.enfermaria E WHERE C.consulta_id = 2)
-- INTERSECT
(SELECT DISTINCT E.hospital_id FROM hospital.enfermaria_atendimento EA 
INNER JOIN hospital.enfermaria E WHERE E.enfermaria_id = 1);
```

However, seems like there is no such thing in MySQL (INTERSECT). This is to allow me to create a TRIGGER BEFORE INSERT in my table hospital.enfermaria_atendimento to ensure that every tuple is consistent.

enfermaria_atendimento table contains consulta_id and enfermaria_id attributes. Both attributes are foreign keys to different tables (table consulta and table enfermaria) which (both) have a relationship with table hospital. A new tuple to enfermaria_atendimento cannot contain a consulta_id related to a enfermaria_id that belongs to a different hospital_id.

I hard coded specific enfermaria_id=1 and hospital_id=2 just for simulation purpose. Instead of specific numbers i intend to use the information from the new. insert

I tried to simulate the INTERSECT parameter with this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.hospital_id FROM hospital.enfermaria_atendimento EA 
INNER JOIN hospital.enfermaria E WHERE E.enfermaria_id = 1
WHERE E.hospital_id 
    IN (
        SELECT C.hospital_id FROM hospital.consulta C
        INNER JOIN hospital.enfermaria_atendimento EA ON C.consulta_id=2
    );
```

But no success so far...

Comment: Your `JOIN` clauses do not have `ON` conditions. This is why the queries take a lot to execute and you need `DISTINCT` to remove the duplicates (that shouldn't appear if the correct conditions are used.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `INTERSECT` in your case could be simulated like below (using additional join):

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.hospital_id 
FROM hospital.enfermaria_atendimento EA 
INNER JOIN hospital.enfermaria E ON 
  ?? = ?? -- put conditions here
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT C.hospital_id
  FROM hospital.consulta C
  INNER JOIN hospital.enfermaria_atendimento EA ON 
    ?? = ?? -- put conditions here
  WHERE C.consulta_id = 2
  ) F ON E.hospital_id = F.hospital_id
WHERE
  E.enfemaria_id = 1
```

You have to specify joining conditions, they are missing in your query.

Comment: I see where the mistake was now....thanks a lot for your help, i really appreciate it!

Comment: You may [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you find it helpful. Glad I could help :)

Comment: I just did, but unfortunately i wasn't able to find out the solution for this. This query doesn't solve all the cases....so i am stuck with this structure now (see next comment)

Like trying to execute an intersection (with no success)...been stuck on this for hours and hours :(

Comment: SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT C.hospital_id
FROM hospital.hospital H
INNER JOIN hospital.consulta C ON H.hospital_id = C.hospital_id
WHERE C.consulta_id = 3) F1
WHERE EXISTS
SELECT * FROM ((SELECT DISTINCT E.hospital_id
FROM hospital.hospital H2
INNER JOIN hospital.enfermaria E ON E.hospital_id = H2.hospital_id
WHERE E.enfermaria_id = 1) F2) WHERE F1.hospital_id = F2.hospital_id

Comment: Without explaining the causes and results there is not much I can work with. Also, please attach the code as an edit to your original question instead of a comment. It's unreadable atm.